# Tell coworker nicely that it's their job

Tags: colleagues

Coworker is working on a spreadsheet that I will start using. He is asking me to test it to see if it's good to go. How to tell coworker to get this thing working before sending to me and that he should test it and make sure it's good instead of me doing it?

Yes I can test as an end user but I don't want to help him test the functionality of the sheet itself or the data (he has access to all the old data to validate it just like me). I believe that's his job but I don't want to be rude.

I will be running this not him but he is in charge of making the sheet.

Comment: I think some more details would help your question. At this moment it isn't clear why you refuse to do an acceptance test of a tool your are going to use.

Comment: Okay, let's say they come back and say "I've tested it and it works". What are you going to do now?

Comment: because since he has access to all the data I have and is in charge of creating this sheet I believe he should get it working himself

Comment: @PhilipKendall then I use it and if it works great if not then its not my problem he can handle the fix.

Comment: How are you going to determine "if it works"? By... errrr.... testing it?

Comment: No I will not test I will use it if it breaks then that's not my problem.  Testing implies I will run it in some test environment and check possibly dummy data which is extra work.

Comment: Of course if I should help him test it then I will thats why I'm asking here.

Comment: Certainly your definition of "testing" to mean "run on dummy data" is not a universally accepted definition; I regularly test on real data. If you have specifically confirmed with your coworker that is what they mean, please edit that into your question because it significantly changes how people will understand the question.

Comment: Have you considered that maybe your coworker already does test, but that he wants you to test too, in case he missed some use case he didn't know about? Or in case there was some misunderstanding somewhere?

Answer (score 14):

I don't see a problem here. I test things before giving them to people, but I still ask them to test that it meets all their needs as well to confirm I can stop working on it. I assume your colleague is doing the same.

Answer (score 4):

It is always good idea to have a second pair of eyes. In my previous work all reports went through another engineer's eyes and in my current work my manager always go through the software I wrote, not through the code, but they use it and give feedback.

I think you approach this wrong way. You are not doing the work for them, you just give feedback to ensure good quality of work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you should be doing the "final" test.

But interim testing should be down to him to iterate towards a final "user ready" product.